Map the domain $\Omega$ onto the upper half plane
(Conformal) map the domain $\Omega$ onto the upper half plane

I would like solution verification on this; for reader interpretation, note that the interval $[-1,0]$ is a slit and is meant to be excluded from the surrounding area $\Omega$.
First, I seek to open the arms to get a right half plane. If we take a point on one of the arms, say $e^{ \pm i \pi/4}$, then squaring gives $e^{i \pm \pi / 2}$. Thus, the map $T_1(z) = z^2$ gives us a left half plane. Now, rotate it $90^\circ$ clockwise with $T_2(z)=-i$ to get an upper half plane.
It remains to remove the slit. Note that the endpoints of the slit are $0$ and $i$. We can use the map $T_3(z) = \sqrt{z^2+h^2}$ (where $h$ is the coefficient of the upper end point of the slit; in our case, $h=1$ since the upper end point of the slit is $i = 1\cdot i)$. That is, $T_3(z) = \sqrt{z^2+1}$. This collapses the slit to the real axis. Hence, we are done.

Please take a careful look at the text of the solution-verification tag. A question with that tag must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
